# PIC (16F627A) inverted inputs

Tags: pic, input

I'm having problem with inputs of my PIC.

There is somethink like "default value" on all inputs set to logical 1 so if I want to change the state I need to pass GND.

How can I turn it "otherwise"? This is begining of my code:

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic.h>
#include <pic16f627a.h>

__CONFIG(WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & FOSC_INTOSCCLK & MCLRE_OFF & BOREN_OFF & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int i, j;

    unsigned short count = 0;

    TRISA = 0;
    TRISB = 0b11110000;
    PORTA = 0;
    PORTB = 0;
    nRBPU = 0;
    CMCONbits.CM = 7;
    ...
```

I don't understand electronics very much and I'm also kind of new to programming in C.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What you are talking about is a _pullup resistor._ And I am pretty sure that the PIC doesn't have a pulldown. That means, you are only able to make the default value logic 1. Unless you use an external pulldown resistor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid now. Thank you so much. Could you please send this as an aswer so I can accept it?

Comment: By the way, if I would like to use internal pull-up resistors, is there any way of "inverting" inputs so I still can use "positive logic"? Now I used "if (!RB0) { ... }" which was trigged when RB0 button was pushed. I would like to not have to use negation in every condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon is known as a *pullup resistor.* As seen on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor) page, it is widely used in conjunction with a physical switch. When pressed, the switch "pulls" the input low, overcoming the resistor's high impedance.

Also, on some MCUs there is an option to *invert* the pin's function. For example, on the AVR XMega, you can configure it so that both input and output will be inverted. I am not sure whether this specific PIC supports such feature. You'll have to dig through the datasheet.

Comment: is there another way to inverse pins other than by configuring procesor? Like redefining variables or something like that? I'm not skilled in C so much ...